# SQL Server : USE database precedence issue

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am having issues with using a `USE Database; GO` when the statement is within an if..else statement. My guess is that the `USE Database; GO` was suppose to be used at the top of the script or sql statement.

Maybe someone could help me come up with a different way of approaching this, what I am trying to do is, check if a particular database exists if it does drop a particular user access from that specific database. The way I was thinking of doing it is as follows ...

```
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='MyDB')
 BEGIN
   USE MyDB
   GO
   DROP USER [tester]
   .
   .
   .
 END
ELSE
 PRINT 'MyDB database is not available'
```

I chopped the sql script to a smaller version so I don't clutter this post so be aware there are some other logic that has been left out after `DROP USER`

EDITED:
I have tried various ways to check if the db exists so everyone knows
Tried

```
if db_id('MyDB') is not null
or
if object_id('MyDB', 'U')
```

But, it always goes directly to `use MyDb` first and I don't know why and how to work around it.

Comment: GO [isn't a T-SQL statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx). It's just a command to the front-end utility you're using to send the batch of statements you've entered up to that point. That's why it breaks if it's between a BEGIN and END -- it finishes the batch in the middle of the block.

Comment: @MattGibson I have taken out the Go, added a semicolon right after `MyDB` and that didn't work. That's why I have turned to stack overflow

Comment: Exactly what do you experience? Does the EXISTS() query return true? What does "it always goes directly to use MyDb" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you cannot put `GO` in the middle of a group of SQL statements that are dependent on each other because:

1. `GO` indicates the end of one compiled batch and the beginning of the next.  Most statement contexts (like an `IF..ELSE`) cannot span a `GO`.  And,
2. `GO` isn't even a SQL statment, it's a Management Studio/SQLCMD command, so it won't be recognized anywhere else.

Your situation is a common need, but there's no one single solution.  For the specific case that you list, using Dynamic SQL is probably the best approach:

```
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='MyDB')
 BEGIN
   EXEC('
     USE MyDB
     EXEC(''
       DROP USER [tester]
        .
        .
        . 
     '')  
   ')
 END
ELSE
 PRINT 'MyDB database is not available'
```

This leverages the fact that Dynamic SQL exections each constitute their own batch to both substitue for `GO`s effect (starting a new batch)  and to isolate the peculiar interactions of `USE` with the compiler.  It's very kludgy of course because of the need to "double-wrap" things after the `USE..GO` commands.

Note also that because of this double-wrapping any strings inside it will have to be quadruple-quoted.

Comment: I am going to try this and I will update you. Thank you for taking the time to give me a heads up.

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much. I am changing my sql script as you recommended cause I don't want to see the same issue every again!

Answer (score 1):

The following works OK for me (gives all expected results, I also tested with some select statements after the USE which worked fine when the DB was found, and threw an error if the DB was out of scope which is expected)

```
USE master
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='SomeDatabase') BEGIN
   USE SomeDatabase
   print 'Database available'
END ELSE
 PRINT 'Database is not available'
```

Can you explain further what you are expecting and what you are seeing?

Update:

This also works fine:

```
USE master
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='SomeDatabase') BEGIN
   USE SomeDatabase
   print 'Database available'
   print 'more stuff'
   print 'even more stuff'

END ELSE
 PRINT 'Database is not available'
```

However:

```
USE master
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='SomeDatabase') BEGIN
   USE SomeDatabase
   print 'Database available'
   print 'more stuff'
   print 'even more stuff'

END ELSE
 PRINT 'Database is not available'
 print 'something else when the db is unavail' -- This line will always print regardless
```

Update: I can also do this (FYI I'm running these in 2008 Management Studio)

```
USE master
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='JMCExpenseService')
 BEGIN
   USE SomeDatabase       
   select * from SomeTableInSomeDatabase

   USE AnotherDatabase
   SELECT * FROM TableInAnotherDatabase    

   USE SomeDatabase       
   select * from SomeOtherTableInSomeDatabase

END
ELSE
 PRINT 'MyDB database is not available'
```

I get 3 resultsets with the expected data - not sure if this works in 2005 but I can't see why not. How are you executing your query?

Edit:

I see my issue - this dies if the DB doesn't exist, I used `USE SomeDatabase2` to test it and it so happens that I do actually have a DB called this. This totally chokes if the DB doesn't actually exist! I guess dynamic SQL is the only way to get this done (I do loathe dynamic SQL)

Comment: Forgive me if I am not being clear and thank you for the answer.I could run what you have answered perfectly fine but the problem is when you have multiple lines to print, it complains about not finding. Try adding one more print statement and you will see what i am talking about

Comment: Not sure what you are on about - I can print as many times as I want without a problem. Do you mean the last print statement? I can see that being a problem since it's not enclosed in a BEGIN/END block therefore any subsequent print statements will always be executed since they are outside any program flow blocks

Comment: The problem here is that the `USE` command does not get executed until *after* the sql batch it is in is compiled.  So any statements after it in the same batch will still be compiled against the DB you were in *before* the `USE` was executed, which tends to cause strange errors.

Comment: Not true, in SQL management studio 2008 anyway - but it does depend on how you run your query; I can run these batches with as many USE statements as I need without any GO statements required and the database context will switch as the script runs. I can't comment on how it would run via SQLCMD or as part of a sproc, but I could test

Comment: Off the top of my head I'm pretty sure you can't USE in a sproc anyway since a single batch can't switch DB contexts

Comment: I got the same error when I ran your second code snippet. The sql server I am using is 2005 and maybe some setup is wrong on mine which I doubt but its really really annoying that you can run your second code snippet but I can't

Comment: Must be a SQL2005 thing then - I might have a SQL2005 instance somewhere I can test it on. Maybe this is something MS updated in 2008/R2

Comment: Though having said that - a simple print statement should work regardless of the DB context. I assume you ran exactly the same query as I ran (just with your DB in place of my DB name?)

Comment: nope, I just tried it on sql server 2012 and it gave me an error saying `Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Database 'SomeDatabase' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.`

Comment: Ok that's strange - I'm running SQL2012 too and it works fine for me. Maybe compatibility level? Did you run SQL2012 server or SQL2012 management studio connecting to SQL2005?

Comment: Ah no just realised - it's me, I stuck a 2 on the end of the database name in the script to test it and it turns out I do actually have a database called that so when compiling it was actually finding the database! Argh. Yes I get the same error, and now I understand what Barry is saying - that the script compiler dies trying to USE a database that doesn't exist even though a conditional branch might not even execute that USE statement

Comment: @Charleh Thank you so much for the answers but I am accepting the other answer since that one does what I need it to do exactly. It's messy but what ever it takes to do the job.

Comment: FWIW, Your script works the same on SQL 2005 (I just tested it).  It's got some puzzling aspects that I am still trying to figure out ...

Comment: Gail Shaw just explained the parts I was confused about here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1516144-338-1.aspx?Update=1

Comment: No probs @Abuelo theres no way it would have worked when the DB didn't exist with my solution anyway!