# sp_MSForEachDB doesn't seem to like GO

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have used this SP before. Now, I am trying to permission a user to 50 odd databases that start with the same letters, using the code below. It looks like it does not like "GO" in the code. Why is that ? and what is the work around?

Thanks for your time.. :)

RM

```
exec sp_MSForEachDB
'
IF ''?'' LIKE ''MYDBNames%''
BEGIN
Use [?]
Go
CREATE USER [MYDOMAIN\Analysts] FOR LOGIN [MYDOMAIN\Analysts]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N''db_owner'', N''MYDOMAIN\Analysts''
GO
END
```

'

Comment: AFAIK `GO` is not a "SQL" statement, it's only used by the client tools. You will need separate the statements using `;` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I know my answer was ignored, but please don't ignore this warning:  ***sp_MSForEachDb IS BAD NEWS***. See [here](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/02/08/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior.aspx), [here](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp-msforeachdb.aspx) and [here](http://mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=2201).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just explained this in another question yesterday ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102165/sql-server-use-database-precedence-issue/20102814#20102814)).  This essence is this: `GO` isn't a SQL statement, it's an SSMS/SQLCMD command that is used to separate batches (groups of SQL statements that are compiled together). So you cannot use it in things like stored procedures or Dynamic SQL. Also, very few statement contexts can cross over a `GO` boundary (transactions and session-level temp tables are about it).

However, because both stored procedures and Dynamic SQL establish their own separate batches/execution contexts, you can use these to get around the normal need for `GO`, like so:

```
exec sp_MSForEachDB
'
    IF ''?'' LIKE ''MYDBNames%''
    BEGIN
    Use [?]
    EXEC(''
        CREATE USER [MYDOMAIN\Analysts] FOR LOGIN [MYDOMAIN\Analysts]
        '')
    EXEC('' EXEC sp_addrolemember N''''db_owner'''', N''''MYDOMAIN\Analysts'''' '')
    END
'
```

Comment: It's also configurable. You can change SSMS to use a different batch separator if you want, and ignore GO.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yes, I was aware of that.  It has little use, however, and is normally only seen as a devious April Fool's prank on a colleague. (try changing it to "SELECT" sometime ;-) )

Answer (score 2):

The word `GO` is a batch separator and is not a SQL keyword. In SSMS you can go to options and change it to anything - `COME` for example.

Try this:

```
exec sp_MSForEachDB
'
IF ''?'' LIKE ''MYDBNames%''
BEGIN;
Use [?];
CREATE USER [MYDOMAIN\Analysts] FOR LOGIN [MYDOMAIN\Analysts];
EXEC sp_addrolemember N''db_owner'', N''MYDOMAIN\Analysts'';
END;'
```

Comment: this made me smile so badly, I knew it was no "real" sql keyword, but did not know you can customize it, anyone looking for this: the option can be found under options->query execution->batch seperator; I am thinking about changing it to "HELL YEA" everywhere, well maybe next 1st of april :D

Comment: One more tip - Modify SQLFile.sql which is located in the default installation path. Or search for the file ;). Change it to create a template for all new queries - on all my team's installations, I change it to read - " Format and comment your code. You may not be around when the next change request comes in :)"

Answer (score 2):

1. Just stop using `GO`, it's not necessary (and it's not even T-SQL; it's just a batch separator for Management Studio).
2. Stop using `sp_MSForEachDB`. Oh, the problems (if you want proof, see [here](https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior), [here](https://sqlblog.org/2020/01/31/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb) and [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-part-2/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)).

Here is code that does this without using any stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';
  CREATE USER [MYDOMAIN\Analysts] FOR LOGIN [MYDOMAIN\Analysts];
  EXEC sys.sp_addrolemember N''db_owner'', N''MYDOMAIN\Analysts'';
  -- actually should use ALTER ROLE now
  
'
FROM sys.databases
WHERE state = 0 -- online
AND name LIKE N'MyDBName%';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @RBarryYoung's answer, an embedded exec() can be used to avoid needing a "go" when the command carries the requirement that it must be the "first within a batch."  I don't think the question's example needs a "go" but the headline itself may lead people here.

Here is a basic SP to wrap this that support's DDL statements like "create proc" and provides some error messages.  I'm probably the ~5th person to do this and this one isn't the end all.

Blessing/Curse:  There is a call to Common.ufn_UsvToNVarcharKeyTable() which you may need to patch in your own CSV splitter or remove:

```
alter proc [Common].[usp_ForEachDatabase]   
    @pSql                 nvarchar(max),
    @pDatabaseNameLikeOpt nvarchar(300) = null,   -- Optional pattern to match with like
    @pDatabaseNameCsvOpt  nvarchar(max) = null,   -- Optional list of DBs
    @pJustPrintDbNames    bit = 0,                -- Don't exec, just print database names
    @pDebug               bit = 1                 -- may add additional print statements
as
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Purpose:  Execute SQL on each database.  Replacement for the standard sp_MSForEachDB which has a size character 
              limit and requires an exec() within for DDL commands which must be the first in a batch.

     Sources: Ideas from http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS-SQL-Server/SQL-Server-2005/Q_26337388.html
              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125430
              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819095/

    Modified    By          Description
    ----------  ----------  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2014.10.14  crokusek    Initial version. Pieces from internet.
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
begin try

    declare databaseCursor cursor local forward_only static for
        select IsNull(sd.Name, ud.Name) as Name,
               --
               -- If a list was specified, flag when a name was not found
               --
               convert(bit, iif(sd.Name is null, 1, 0)) as IsNotFound   
          from 
             (
                select Name from sys.databases
                 where Name not in ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')                            
                   and is_distributor = 0 -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819095/
             ) sd             
          full outer join ( select Value as Name from Common.ufn_UsvToNVarcharKeyTable(@pDatabaseNameCsvOpt, ',' ) ) ud
            on ud.Name = sd.Name            
         where (@pDatabaseNameLikeOpt is null or IsNull(sd.Name, ud.Name) like @pDatabaseNameLikeOpt)
           and (@pDatabaseNameCsvOpt is null or ud.Name is not null)
         order by IsNull(sd.Name, ud.Name);

    declare 
        @matchingDatabaseNames nvarchar(max),
        @databaseName nvarchar(300),
        @isNotFound bit,
        @errorCount int = 0,
        @successCount int = 0,
        --
        -- Use an embedded exec() to place the user command(s) in a separate context to avoid errors like: 
        --      CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE must be the first statement in a query batch.
        --         
        @sqlExec nvarchar(max) = N'exec (''' + replace(@pSql, '''', '''''') + ''')';

    open databaseCursor
    fetch next from databaseCursor into @databaseName, @isNotFound;
    while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin                                                
        if (@isNotFound = 1)
        begin
            print 'Error: Database ' + @databaseName + ' was not found.';
            set @errorCount += 1;        
        end
        else
        begin
            set @matchingDatabaseNames = coalesce(@matchingDatabaseNames + ',', '') + @databaseName; -- Create Csv

            print 'Database: ' + @databaseName;    

            if (@pJustPrintDbNames = 0)
            begin        
                declare 
                    @execSql nvarchar(max) = 'use ' + @databaseName + ';' + char(10) + @sqlExec;

                begin try
                    exec (@execSql)  
                    set @successCount += 1;        
                end try
                begin catch
                    select @databaseName as [Database],
                           error_number() as ErrorNumber,
                           error_severity() as ErrorSeverity,
                           error_state() as ErrorState,
                           error_procedure() as ErrorProcedure,
                           error_line() as ErrorLine,
                           error_message() as ErrorMessage;
                    set @errorCount += 1;        
                end catch  
            end
        end
        fetch next from databaseCursor into @databaseName, @isNotFound;
    end

    if (@pJustPrintDbNames = 1)
        print @matchingDatabaseNames; -- this can then be used as input
    else                                                
        print 'Completed with ' + convert(varchar(30), @errorCount) + ' Errors ' + 
              'and ' +  convert(varchar(30), @successCount) + ' Successes.';
end try
begin catch
     if (xact_state() = -1)
        rollback;        
    -- Log / Rethrow
end catch
go
```

Usage:

```
declare 
    @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
create proc usp_ReplaceEachSingleQuoteWithTwoSingleQuotesInTheDefinition
...';

exec [Common].[usp_ForEachDatabase]   
    @pSql                 = @sql,
    @pDatabaseNameLikeOpt = null, 
    @pDatabaseNameCsvOpt  = null,
    @pJustPrintDbNames    = 0,
    @pDebug               = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why not use a cursor?**

They are great for management tasks like this.  As long as the record set is small, they perform well.

The code below creates a SQL statement for each database that uses the ; to combine multiple tasks.

Unlike the code above, it remove any existing users before creating a new one.  Avoids a possible issue.

Then it executes the code.  If you want, you could even log these adhoc requests to a internal table and add error checking.

Good luck.

```
--
--  EXEC same statements against several like databases
--

    -- Declare local variables
    DECLARE @STMT NVARCHAR(4000);

    -- Allocate cursor, return table names
    DECLARE MYTRG CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
      SELECT 
          ' use [' + ltrim(rtrim(d.name)) + ']; ' +
          ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N''[MYDOMAIN\Analysts]'') DROP USER [MYDOMAIN\Analysts]; ' +
          ' CREATE USER [MYDOMAIN\Analysts] FOR LOGIN [MYDOMAIN\Analysts] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[DBO]; ' +
          ' sp_addrolemember N''db_owner'', N''MYDOMAIN\Analysts''; ' as STMT 
      FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases d
      WHERE d.name like 'MYDBNames%'
      ORDER BY d.name;

    -- Open cursor    
    OPEN MYTRG;

    -- Get the first row    
    FETCH NEXT FROM MYTRG INTO @STMT;

    -- While there is data
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) 
    BEGIN   

        -- Show detail database info
    EXEC sp_executesql @STMT;

    -- Get the first row    
    FETCH NEXT FROM MYTRG INTO @STMT;

    END;

    -- Close the cursor
    CLOSE MYTRG; 

    -- Release the cursor
    DEALLOCATE MYTRG;
```